# user.is_authenticated in Users List

Tags: django, django-users

Despite many searches, I have not found any solution to my problem : Content for authenticated user does not display on the view displaying users list.

My app has a view displaying a list of users:

**views.py**

```
def UserListView(request):
    user = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    return render(request, 'accounts/user_list.html', {"user": user})
```

A base template with this navbar:

**base.html**

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <li><a class="nav-item" href={% url 'logout' %}>Logout</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li><a class="nav-item" href={% url 'login' %}>Login</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Even if the user is logged, The menu displays Login instead of Logout.
I am suspecting a problem of context?
Any advice is welcome :)

Comment: You're passing a list of users to the context. You should be iterating over them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `user` from the view is clashing with the `user` from the auth context processor. Since the variable from the view is a queryset, it doesn't have an `is_authenicated` attribute, so `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` always evaluates to `False`.

Since the view displays a list of multiple users, it would be better to rename it to `users`.

```
def user_list_view(request):
    users = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    return render(request, 'accounts/user_list.html', {"users": users})
```

You'll then need to change the loop in your `accounts/user_list.html` template, for example:

```
{% for u in users %}
  {{ u.username }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Alasdair, that's it :)